# Ubuntu 18 - Laptop Keyboard not working during installation

Tags: keyboard, vmware

I have a laptop Lenovo ThinkPad x240 running windows 10 64 bit. I have a vmware workstation 11 and I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.01. I already have a CentOS VM and everything is working fine there. When I try to install Ubuntu, the keyboard stops working at the installation stage, here:

[image: keyboard not working during installation]

I can't type anything. The mouse works, but the laptop keyboard doesn't. Any ideas how I might fix that so I can install the Ubuntu guest?

By the way, additional info, when I was beginning to install, there was a pop-up asking something about the keyboard - stupid me did not read and said yes, go ahead, and I think that might have been the problem, issue is I don't know what was written :-(

Comment: Reboot installation media, click <F5> (Accessibility) and check On-Screen keyboard, then click <Enter> and run installation with it. If it is not shown try to login with Try Ubuntu and then enable on-screen keyboard from GNOME Control Center (Universal Access -> Typing -> Screen Keyboard). Or if you do not really need VMWare, then install Oracle VM VirtualBox and install Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem trying to install it on my VM. Found a simple solution. I gave more power to the machine, trying to meet the requirement. The keyboard worked once i gave it 4gb of ram. Good luck!

Comment: I had it at 1024.  Setting to 4096 worked.  I also noticed when I selected to install the popup had a title bar that was not there before.  This was happening to me on Oracle VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and it was driving me crazy, tried about 10 different things, what actually worked for me was when you get to that screen where it asks "who are you" right click where you would type "your name" and go down and select "insert emoji", and then just select the "who are you" screen again, this  will highlight the empty input box in orange and finally allow you to input you information.

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently too, however I managed to work around this issue via the KB test screen. I typed in "temp" in the test field and copied it to the clipboard. Then when I came to the "Computer name" field I just pasted "temp" as well as for the cpu name, and log in and password. I can straighten it out once the OS is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simple

- While installing, once you get to the section that require you to connect to the internet...as you type your Wi-Fi password... also type something like "USERPC" and copy it
- then paste it in the "who are you" window and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing Ubuntu 19.10 in libvirt: Navigating the dialogs with Tab, Space, and Enter worked, but entering text did not.

Enabling the on-screen keyboard in the boot menu fixed it for me. I didn't even have to use the on-screen keyboard; just enabling it made normal typing work.

Instructions:

- Boot the install image.
- Press a key when the Keyboard = Human icons appear.
- Select a language.
- Press F5 to open the Accessibility menu.
- Choose On-Screen Keyboard.
- Choose an install option from the main menu and proceed.

Maybe caused by this bug?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/548891

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/136874/ubuntu-10-04-doesnt-accept-keyboard-input-when-running-under-vmware-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened while I was installing Ubuntu via VMware.

My solution was just restarting my VM, and it worked after wards.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened while I was installing Ubuntu via VMware.

My solution was to go to VMWare Edit->Preferences->Input and

to disable both

**Grab keyboard and mouse input on mouse click**

and

**Grab keyboard and mouse input on key press**